# CSVPrinter quotes the value even when it does not have a delimiter or line separator

Tags: csv, apache-commons-csv

When CSVFormat's quoteMode is set to MINIMAL, it should quote the value only when the value contains a delimiter (,) or line separator '\n' according to the [javadoc](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/archives/1.4/apidocs/index.html).
But it does quoting even if the value contains hash (#). Please see below example code

```
  @Test
  public void testCSV() throws IOException {
    String[] row = new String[]{"simple text","##5##"};
    CSVFormat CSV_FORMAT = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withRecordSeparator("\n").withQuoteMode(QuoteMode.MINIMAL);

    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter(1024);
    CSVPrinter csvPrinter = new CSVPrinter(stringWriter, CSV_FORMAT);
    csvPrinter.printRecord(row);
    System.out.println("sw : " + stringWriter.getBuffer().toString());
    csvPrinter.close();
    stringWriter.close();
  }
```

**output** :  sw : simple text,"##5##"

Please suggest a way in which I can avoid quoting in such cases.